# Save Array of Selected Rows in UITableview. iOS.

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, multi-select

I am trying to save the selected rows in a `UITableView` to an `NSArray` .

```
[self.categoriesTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

is normally outputted as:

```
"<NSIndexPath: 0x15583590> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}"
```

I want to be able to save the array to user defaults as integers. e.g If row 0, 2 and 3 are selected I want to save an array as follows:

```
0,2,3 o NSMutableArray *numberArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:0,2,3, nil];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaultsForCategories = [NSUserDefaults
standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *selectedRows = [self.categoriesTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

[userDefaultsForCategories setObject:self.selectedRows forKey:@"chosenRows"];
```

Any help . I am so stuck.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for state restoration?

Comment: @user2320861 . Yes I basically want to save the rows I selected in user defaults os that when I come back to that screen I can select the rows from the saved user defaults array

Comment: Do you need to save the selections for when a user quits your app and comes back, or are you talking about saving them during one session with your app ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually reading about NSCoder right now as I'm learning how to save state information for state preservation and restoration. It seems to me that on the face of it, leveraging NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver (concrete subclasses of NSCoder) might be the way to go. NSKeyedArchiver "provides a way to encode objects (and scalar values) into an architecture-independent format that can be stored in a file."

Read up on it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSKeyedArchiver

Then in your `viewDidLoad:` you might check for a saved data file and use the saved data to configure the state of your table view.